# How can i add a method to an existing class in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-5

Sorry for my bad english. I have to add a method in Date class in Rails because i want to use my translated day names.
So, i tried:

```
class Date
  def date_of_next(day)
    date  = Date.parse(day)
    delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
    date + delta
  end
end
```

in config/initializers/date_of_next.rb but when i call Date.date_of_next(day) in my controller i get "no method in Date".
How can i do that? And where should i put the file?

Comment: Don't do that.
Use I18n with localize

Comment: you added an instance method, but used singleton one. You should define singleton method, in order to use it: `def self.date_of_next(day)...` - now you can do `Date.date_of_next(day)`

Comment: _"...because i want to use my translated day names"_ – what does that mean?

Comment: @Stefan "day" in italian language. I'm using I18n with it.yml file.
date_of_next("sunday") -> ok.
date_of_next("domenica") -> error.

Comment: @AlexBeginner okay, but none of the proposed solutions allow you to write `date_of_next("domenica")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting monkey patched files under `initializers` is fine (in spite of how "good" monkey patching is itself :)).

You want to change the method definition to following:

```
class Date
  def self.date_of_next(day)
    date  = parse(day)
    delta = date > today ? 0 : 7
    date + delta
  end
end
```

Your problem was that you called a singleton method on the object `Date`, whereas it did not have such method defined.

Comment: I think that it worth saying that class methods are just singleton methods that live in the class's singleton class.

Comment: @nisevi there is no such thing as "class method" in Ruby ;)

Answer (score 3):

As Andrey Deineko points out in his comment (and now answer), you wrote an instance method but called a class method. Try:

```
class Date
  def self.date_of_next(day)
    date  = Date.parse(day)
    delta = date > Date.today ? 0 : 7
    date + delta
  end
end
```

The other (and probably better) way would be more object oriented with an instance method:

```
class Date
  def date_of_next
    delta = self > Date.today ? 0 : 7
    self + delta
  end
end

day.date_of_next    # you might want to pick a better name
```

One more hint: monkey patching (extending an existing class in such a way) is not the best solution on the longer run. You might want to switch to different patterns some day.